# Defining macros in LyX

Tags: macros, lyx

I am having a problem defining a script that I got as a macro in LyX (or even making it "work" in LyX).
The script I have is the following:

```
\newcommand{\from}{\mathbin{\vbox{\baselineskip=3pt\lineskiplimit=0pt
                     \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}}}}
```

It suppose to be three dots, kind of like `\vdots`, but just lower..
Do you have a clue how to make it work in LyX?
I don't even know if this script (which is I suppose in Latex) is suitable to LyX.

Comment: What do you want to do?  Do you want to know how to make Lyx accept that definition?  Do you want to know how to run user-supplied Tex macros in Lyx?  Do you want to know how to add symbols to the symbols Lyx recognises?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to tell that.. I would like to know how to make lyx accept that definition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LyX uses LaTeX as the backend, so in principle you can use any LaTeX macro in LyX.

For your case, you can go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble, and add your `\newcommand` there. To use it in a document just type `\from`, but note that this only works in math mode.

LyX won't necessarily show it formatted as you're typing but it will come up in a PDF export.

Answer (score 3):

LyX includes a feature for inserting macros that if used will (in most cases) replace the defined command with a LyX graphical representation of it's definition.

To use macros, do `Insert > Math > Macro` and insert your to be defined command and its content.

Alternatively, or if something goes haywire while the content is being typed, you can write out the entire `\newcommand...` in normal text mode, and then in one fell swoop convert it to a macro by highlighting it, and then applying `Insert > Math > Inline formula` (or the corresponding keyboard shortcut).